# Div col-sm resize

Tags: html, image, size

I am currently working with Div col sm/md/lg and I have a setup of three images in their three respective col-sm divs. I need the pictures to be a little bit bigger however when I adjust the col-sm-4 to 5 the third picture wraps below, but I need them to all stay on the same row. I did some research and found that if your columns amount to more than 12 it will automatically wrap. However, there is plenty of white space on the left and right of my three columns. Is there a way to use some of that space to make my div colums larger without wrapping?

Here is my code for one of the columns:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 eq-items">
<div class="row"><img src="/content/pexels-anna-shvets-4226122.jpg" alt="" title="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 300px;" data-d2l-editor-default-img-style="true" /><br />
<div class="col-sm-12">
<h3>MyFIRE Instructor Training</h3>
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">The MyFIRE instructor training courses are provided to help introduce the MyFIRE learning platform. These courses expand upon various training materials that will assist in the addition of content, resources, media, and tools to enhance the student learning experience. We invite you to explore and learn about the many capabilities of SEU's learning platform. Please note: Permissions vary based on instructor role so some editing options may not be available.</span></p>
<p style="text-decoration: underline;"><span style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;"><a href="/d2l/lor/viewer/viewFile.d2lfile/30233/4225,-1/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">MyFIRE Training Courses for Instructors</a></span></p>
<h1 dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;"><strong>Contact:&nbsp;</strong></span></h1>
<p dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-family: verdana, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt;">idttraining@seu.edu</span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to initialize de class "row".

Then, inside this class, you configure the columns. Since you want three columns in any size you have to use the class "col-XX-4" (3 cols x 4 = 12 in total).

I suggest you only use "col-sm-4" for each image like in the example:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/coffee-cup-beans-on-old-260nw-547416751.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/coffee-cup-beans-on-old-260nw-547416751.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/coffee-cup-beans-on-old-260nw-547416751.jpg" class="img-thumbnail">
        </div>
</div>
```